# Randomly selecting element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup.

```
<div class="area 1">
    <div id="area-count">
        23
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 2">
    <div id="area-count">
        52
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 3">
    <div id="area-count">
        0
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 4 friendly">
    <div id="area-count">
        21
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 5">
    <div id="area-count">
        23
    </div>
</div>
```

What I wish to do is `alert()` the number found in one of the elements picked at random. I also wish not to have any element with a class of `friendly` so far I have this, just to try and `alert()` a random number before I try and negate the class `friendly`.

```
randomElement = $("area-count").get().sort(function(){
            return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5}).slice(0,1);
            alert(randomElement);
```

This however outputs nothing... where am I going wrong?

Comment: id attributes should be unique. Not that that solves your problem. Consider making area-count a class.

Comment: FYI, spaces in the class attribute signify multiple classes. For example, many of your divs have the class 'area', but only one of them has the class '1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see nobody reads carefully!

So with all the good advises about the [classes and ids<sup>w3.org</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

> id = name [CS] - This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name
> must be unique in a document.
>
> class = cdata-list [CS] This attribute
> assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number
> of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple
> class names must be separated by white space characters.

and based on [tvanfosson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933418/179669) :

```
var elements = $( ".area-count" ).parent().not( ".friendly" ).children(),
    index = Math.floor ( Math.random() * elements.length ),
    item = elements.eq ( index );
alert ( item.text() );
```

I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xdvbb/), in order to show only elements, which parents has no class *".friendly"* I left only 2 elements without this class. So the possible results will be only 0 or 52.

This, is **not** an optimal variant! It is working as the requirements are stated.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your id's need to be unique.  You should change `<div id="area-count">` to `<div class="area-count">`
2. There's no need to sort them.  Simply figure out the number of items (length of the jQuery) and pick a random number between 0 and the number of items minus 1.  Select this item using from the collection using `eq`.

Like this:

```
<div class="area 1">
    <div class="area-count">
        23
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 2">
    <div id="area-count">
        52
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 3">
    <div class="area-count">
        0
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 4 friendly">
    <div class="area-count">
        21
    </div>
</div>
<div class="area 5">
    <div class="area-count">
        23
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var counts = $('.area-count'),
        index = Math.floor( Math.random() * counts.length ),
        item = counts.eq(index);

    alert(item.text());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.fn.rand = function(){
    return this.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length));
};
var randomElement = $('[id="area-count"]:not(.friendly)').rand();
alert(randomElement.text());
```

Also note: ID's must be unique, the snippet above gets around that by using the attribute equals selector.

Comment: I suppose in the hurry you didn't test this. The class "friendly" is applied to the parent element of the one with class "area-count".

Comment: @Bakudan it's more for concept if anything. No real reason to test, it's already been thoroughly tested. The poster should be able to take what I post and apply it to their situation. That's just a small selector change.

Answer (score 0):

As I've already mentioned about the ids

```
    randomElement = $(".area-count").get().sort(function(){
                return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5}).slice(0,1);
        alert(randomElement);console.log($(randomElement).text());

<div class="area 1">
        <div class="area-count">
            23
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area 2">
        <div class="area-count">
            52
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area 3">
        <div id="area-count">
            0
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area 4 friendly">
        <div class="area-count">
            21
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="area 5">
        <div class="area-count">
            23
        </div>
    </div>​
```